# Weird spaces left on KDE terminals

Tags: terminal, kde, konsole

In the picture you can see the problem (the app on the right).

So I recently installed manjaro i3wm, but I love KDE apps, so I installed konsole, kate and dolphin (which all of them have terminal support) and I found this problem. As you can see, my prompt leaves weird spaces (pc pwd, p.e., should leave one space, but it is a lot more than that; $ls leaves space between letters when I put my cursor on top of it).

I have noticed it only happens on KDE apps, but on all of the ones I have tried.

I used to have arch i3wm (where it worked perfectly) and I have copied some config folders, but I might have missed an important one.

[image: Konsole on the right]

## What I tried:

Changing fonts

Rebooting

Updating

Comment: You need to pick a fixed with font for your terminal.

Comment: @egmont couldo you tell me one I could try?

Comment: look for `monospaced` font

Comment: @jsotola I tried using Noto Sans Mono, but it doesn't help. I changed it in systemsettings, but it doesn't appear to be changed globally in KDE

Answer (score 1):

As @jsotola and @egmont said, it had to do with fonts. However, I found that I had to change it inside konsole: I had to create a profile with a monofont and set it as default.

Kate and dolphin are controlled by konsole, so everything you see in konsole is what you get in kde apps.